# Create Table Syntax

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table in `MySQL` but I keep getting an error of incorrect syntax.  Below is my create table syntax, what is incorrect?

```
CREATE TABLE [Test].[dbo].[Ite](
[ID] [INT] NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
[ite] [varchar](500) NULL,
[dollarvalue] DECIMAL(10,2) NULL)
```

Here is exact error message

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Test].[dbo].[Ite](  [ID] [INT] NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  [i' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're migrating SQL code intended for SQLServer. MySQL uses backticks instead of square brackets, and does not have user. The following code would be suitable for MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `Test`.`Ite` (
`ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ite varchar(500) NULL,
dollarvalue DECIMAL(10,2) NULL);
```

Comment: Ah thank you!  Yes I am migrating SQL Server syntax to MySQL

Comment: And get rid of .dbo.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE 'Test'.'dbo'.'Ite'(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ite varchar(500) NULL,
dollarvalue DECIMAL(10,2) NULL)
```

There is no need for the [] brackets, when making the datatypes for the columns and also the columns names require you to have [] wrapped around them.

Answer (score -3):

create table table name(
column_name column_type)

this is the syntax for creating a table